# Can $\csc(x)\csc(x + y)\sin(y)+\cot(y)$ be rewritten to make its symmetry in $x$ and $y$ more obvious?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry, symmetric-functions

I have a function $f(x, y) = \csc(x) \csc(x + y) \sin(y) + \cot(y)$, and I know from graphing it that the function is symmetric in $x$ and $y$ such that $f(x, y) = f(y, x)$. However, that fact isn't obvious just by looking at the equation, since the two variables don't seem to be treated the same.

**Can the expression be written in such a way that its symmetry is obvious from the expression itself, without needing to graph it?**

I've tried using trig identities to replace the cosecants and cotangent with sines and cosines, using the angle addition identities to isolate one-variable-per-trig-function, and rearranging and regrouping terms, but without success.

Comment: $$f(x,y) = \frac{1 - \cos x \cos y \cos(x + y)}{\sin x \sin y \sin(x + y)}$$ Verification left as an exercise to the asker. :)

Comment: $\frac{f(x,y)+f(y,x)}2$

Comment: @Blue Can you explain how you got to that answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding my comment ...

We have

$$
f(x,y) = \frac{\sin y}{\sin x\sin(x+y)}+\frac{\cos y}{\sin y} 
= \frac{\sin^2y+\sin x\cos y\sin(x+y)}{\sin x\sin y\sin(x+y)}
\tag1$$

The denominator is symmetric in $x$ and $y$, so let's focus on the numerator ...

$$\begin{align}
&\sin^2y+\sin x\cos y(\sin x\cos y+\cos x\sin y) \tag2\\[4pt]
\to\quad &(1-\cos^2y)+\sin^2x\cos^2y+\sin x\cos x\sin y\cos y \tag3\\[4pt]
\to\quad & 1-(1-\sin^2x)\cos^2y+\sin x\cos x\sin y\cos y \tag4\\[4pt]
\to\quad & 1 - \cos^2x\cos^2y+\sin x\cos x\sin y\cos y \tag5\\[4pt]
\to\quad & 1 - \cos x\cos y(\cos x\cos y-\sin x\sin y) \tag6\\[4pt]
\to\quad & 1 - \cos x\cos y \cos(x+y) \tag7
\end{align}$$

Therefore,
$$f(x,y) \;=\; \frac{1-\cos x\cos y\cos(x+y)}{\sin x\sin y\sin(x+y)} \;=\; f(y,x) \tag{$\star$}$$

Comment: I was able to tweak it to get rid of the fraction as $f(x, y) = \csc(x) \csc(y) \csc(x + y) - \cot(x) \cot(y) \cot(x + y)$.

Comment: @Lawton: Personally, I like the fraction. The denominator makes obvious where singularities occur; and the numerator is clearly non-negative (more-specifically, it's bounded by $0$ and $2$), which may be handy to know. Besides, if this function is going to be involved in other manipulations that may be facilitated by converting back to sines and cosines, then you're already there! :)